# How to get AuthorizationCode GrantType working in Symfony 3 with FOSOAuthServerBundle

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, fosoauthserverbundle, symfony-3.2

i'm trying to build a Bootstrap for a Symfony3 REST-Application with OAuth2 Support based on FOSOAuth. My current Implementation is based on the following Sources:

1. [git:maxpou docker-symfony](https://github.com/maxpou/docker-symfony) for Docker Setup
2. [symfony.com - CustomUserProvider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html) for own Userprovider
3. [cause your stuck - oauth2 explained](https://causeyourestuck.io/2016/07/19/oauth2-explained-part-1-principles-terminology/) for OAuth Configuration
4. [bitgandtter.blog - A restful app](https://bitgandtter.blog/2015/09/30/symfony-a-restful-app-security-securing-the-token-path-fixed/) for OAuth in Symfony

and can be found [here](https://github.com/takethefake/SymfonyBootstrap) with all Setupsteps described inside the Readme.

The Client Credentials Login is working right now, but i've got Problems with the AuthorizationCode Flow which does not redirect to `client.local` like described in [cause your stuck - AuthorizationCode](https://causeyourestuck.io/2016/07/19/oauth2-explained-part-3-using-oauth2-bare-hands/#crayon-58ce873ada544866410560) and instead redirects to the `auth_login`-Route again. I thought that FOSOAuth is catching the request and redirects it to `client.local`

Because there are so many Components involved in this i resign on posting code snippets and kindly refer to the [git repository](https://github.com/takethefake/SymfonyBootstrap)

Thanks in advance for any help provided!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I had an error in my UserGeneration Algorithm which generated a wrong PasswordHash because i passed in the email as password and visa versa.
2. i tried to use the `security.context`-Service which is deprecated since Symfony 2.6

The current Bootstrap now works!